# Create custom tag HTML in Ace Editor

Tags: angular7, ace-editor

```
import 'brace';
import 'brace/mode/html';
import 'brace/theme/textmate';
import 'brace/ext/language_tools';
```

How to create custom tag HTML [mytag] with color orange?  I'm using Angular 7 with ngx-ace-wrapper.

Comment: what do you mean by creating tag? do you want to highlight the text "[mytag]" with a different color?

Comment: Yes edit only color

Comment: @auser how implement caseInsensitive?

Comment: add `caseInsensitive: true` to the rule

Answer (score 0):

this.addRules in tag:

```
{
    token : "support.constant",
    regex : "(?:\\[id]|\\[name])"
}
```